# Facebook like and share user tracking

Tags: javascript, php, facebook, facebook-like, tracking

I am using FB share and like plugin on my website. Link below:

`https://developers.facebook.com/docs/plugins/like-button`

I would like to track a user who logged in on my website (I have the user id) and liked and shared a post through FB like and share plugin and when the user does then I would do some `php` coding and reward the user right after the fact that the user likes and shared my post. How am I able to track user like and share?
Thanks,

Comment: _“and reward the user right after the fact that the user likes and shared my post”_ - you are **not allowed** to do that! https://developers.facebook.com/policy#properuse, 4.5) _“Only incentivize a person to log into your app, enter a promotion on your app’s Page, check-in at a place, or to use Messenger to communicate with your business. Don’t incentivize other actions.”_ https://developers.facebook.com/docs/apps/examples-platform-policy-4.5

Answer (score 0):

Read this -
 https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/reference/FB.ui

The example there is pretty clear and you have a callback in which you can do whatever based on the state of the response (they actually shared, they cancelled etc.), you can call your PHP-powered server in the callback and do whatever.

Comment: Yes I understand that but the code `FB.ui(...)` can not run on its own and it needs more code to be added, I am not sure what that code is to be added, can you post the whole code that runs!

Comment: Here's the quick start - https://developers.facebook.com/docs/javascript/quickstart

Answer (score 0):

You cannot get the share callback using this `like` button. You can instead create a `share` button of yours and invoke the Feed Dialog on its click-

```
FB.ui(
{
  method: 'feed',
  name: 'Facebook Dialogs',
  link: 'https://developers.facebook.com/docs/dialogs/',
  picture: 'http://fbrell.com/f8.jpg',
  caption: 'Reference Documentation',
  description: 'Dialogs provide a simple, consistent interface for applications to interface with users.'
},
function(response) {
  if (response && response.post_id) {
    alert('Post was published.');
  } else {
    alert('Post was not published.');
  }
}
);
```

Also see this link: https://developers.google.com/analytics/devguides/collection/gajs/gaTrackingSocial

Comment: What should add above your script and under it because this script is not complete and it is not runing by its own! Thanks,